# Why I cannot mock global variables directly with jest.fn() in react?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I know how to mock global variables with Jest, but the point is I don't know why it cannot be mocked by direct assignment with `jest.fn()`.

Can anyone tell me why `window.loaction = jest.fn()` will cause error?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add a brief description, code, errors of your search/research efforts as is suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some global variables are read-only by specification, `location` is one of them. Jest uses `jsdom` for fake DOM and follows the specification to some extent.

It's a mistake to make `location` a function because it's supposed to be an object.

It's a bad practice to mock methods with assignment like `... = jest.fn()` because this prevents from using Jest's mock restore. Original value needs to to be restored manually when needed, otherwise it's lost for the entire test. `jest.spyOn` is always preferable.

`location` should be defined as `get` accessor:

```
jest.spyOn(window, 'location', 'get').mockReturnValue({ ... });
```

`global.location` and `window.location` are interchangeable because `global === window` in Jest default environment.

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing this answer. I'm afraid that there is a small mistake in the last sentence because one of the globals should be a window. But it is not a big problem, and thank you again!